# How do I pass a generic List as parameter in Java with a defined subtype for that list as value?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use generics to create some flexible data handling, but I am stumbling across a compiler error which I don't know how to get around.
Example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Spielwiese {
    
    class A {
        public A() { }
    }
    
    class B extends A {
        public B() { }
    }
    
    class C<T extends A> {
        T value = null;
        public C() {}
        public void setValue(T v) {
            value = v;
        }
    }

    public static void doSomething(List<C<? extends A>> stuff) { }
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        List<C<B>> stuff = new ArrayList<>(); 
        doSomething(stuff); // compiler error: "The method doSomething(List<C<? extends A>> stuff) is not applicable for the arguments (List<C<B>>)"
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work, even though B extends A as required?

Comment: Even though `C<B>` "is a" `C<? extends A>` (in the same way that `Dog` "is a" `Animal`), `List<C<B>>` is not a `List<C<? extends A>>`, in the same way that [`List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: Basically, the parameter should be `List<? extends C<? extends A>>` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Sweeper posted the solution:

```
public static void doSomething(List<? extends C<? extends A>> stuff) { }
```

This allows to pass a `List<C<B>>` as a parameter just nicely.